# Unexplained error when running npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been publishing this package every week for years.  Today, when I tried to increment the version and publish I get an error:

```
npm notice name:          mypackagename
npm notice version:       6.18.4
npm notice package size:  1.9 MB
npm notice unpacked size: 6.6 MB
npm notice shasum:        897897897987897897
npm notice integrity:     789978979797979799
npm notice total files:   247
npm notice
This operation requires a one-time password.
Enter OTP: 123456
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/mypackagename - unexpected status code from "replace-packument" = 403
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

I have checked that the version # is unique, I have tried going from 6.18.3 to 6.18.4 with no change.  I have never seen this error and have no real idea how to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Came here with the same issue, looks like they're having issues:
https://status.npmjs.org/